# Devise, Rspec and testing get 'new' in RegistrationsController

Tags: rspec, devise

I'm getting the following error :

```
1) RegistrationsController has an registration page load up successfully
     Failure/Error: response.code.should == 200
       expected: 200
            got: "404" (using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in '
```

from this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do
  it "has an registration page load up successfully" do
    get :new
    response.code.should == 200
  end
end
```

I can visit the page successfully in my browser.

Before I get the inevitable "you shouldn't test their code" remarks, I am trying to test my custom register page, which gave me the same errors, so i thought I'd check on the control route of the /register page, which is my sign in page.

Thoughts as to why I'm not getting a 200 but a 404? Debug tips? i can post whatever you need to help out and appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need this in your tests that are accessing any devise routes, cause it doesn't use the router, or rspec doesn't or something like that... [deets here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do
  it "has an registration page load up successfully" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user] #assuming your using :user routes
    get :new
    response.code.should == 200
  end
end
```

It's not enough to have it somewhere else, but when you are rocking their own routes, throw it in there.